# Binding to ArcGIS for server

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, license

I am building a stand alone .NET applications using ArcObjects.
I want to run it on the server, where I have ArcGIS for Server.

I am trying to bind the license at runtime to the ArcGIS server runtime.
But the application giving an error message "Invalid ArcGIS Runtime Binding"

I am using this command

RuntimeManager.Bind(ProductCode.Server)

I don't want to install the engine there or have a license for the engine, because the application run at night when there is no activity , so I want to use the server license

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to have been [answered](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/78479-Binding-stand-alone-application-to-ArcGIS-for-Server?p=276016&viewfull=1#post276016) on the ArcGIS forums.

Since you are using the "ArcGIS *for* Server" idiom, I'm assuming you are working with ArcGIS for Server 10.1, which is a 64-bit application. If so, *your* application needs to be compiled for `AnyCPU`.